# Regex to match letters, numbers and space, including non-ascii characters

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I'm writing a callback function for CodeIgniter's form validation. Only letters, numbers, dash, underscore and space are allowed. I'm currently using this regex:

```
preg_match("/^([-a-z_ ])+$/i", $string)
```

But it won't work with non-ASCII characters like č š ć đ ž â etc. It's a field to enter name and surname and it has to take all these non-ascii characters as well. How to modify this regex to include those characters as well?

Comment: title and content are totally different.

Comment: sorry for that, I didn't know how to express myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **unicode letter** and **unicode number** properties for this:

```
preg_match('/^([-_ \p{L}\p{N}])+$/iu', $string)
```

Update: You may not need a capturing group here:

```
preg_match('/^[-_ \p{L}\p{N}]+$/iu', $string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `u` modifier and `\p{L}` and to add numbers, you may use `[0-9]` or `\p{N}`:

```
preg_match('/^[-\p{L}\p{N}_ ]+$/u', $string)
                ^^^^^^^^^^      ^
```

Note that you do not want to create too much overhead with too many capturing groups. I removed round brackets to achieve best performance. `i` modifier is redundant since there is no literal letter in the pattern.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG3jP2/3)

My regex performance:

[image]

[Anubhava's regex](https://regex101.com/r/uG3jP2/4):

[image]

Comment: Currently accepted solution is too inefficient. Please check my demo links and compare performance.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.php.net/manual/ro/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

u just need to use unicode modifier:

```
preg_match("/^([-a-z_ ])+$/ui", $string)
```